# Turn On/Off 3D printer projector with Python/GPIO

Tags: pi-3, rpi.gpio, python-3

There are similar questions but I don't want to turn on the LED but the 3D printer projector(NQM Plus Light engine) for the image projection.

The pins that I wanted to use are shown in the picture.[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to write some code or information to turn the projector on. {similar to this link: [GUI program for turning on/off a projector via RS232](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47450/gui-program-for-turning-on-off-a-projector-via-rs232)
 }

Please let me know if there is some line of code or the links where I can get the information.
As per the picture these 14 pins can be connected to Raspberry PI GPIO pins. And the pins in the picture that I wanted to use are

3 for LED_ON_OFF

7 RESETZ for ptojector on when kept HIGH and projector OFF when kept LOW.

In case of confusion and not proper information please ask me what kind of information I could give further.

Comment: This is plenty of good information, but what is your question? What did you try so far? How did the results differ from what you expected?

Comment: I have a separate projector On program and it is different from using the GPIO pins. I cannot post it in comment section. And if I edit my question and add what I have tried before might again mislead the information. My question here is to turn the projector(which is 3D printer's light engine for projecting a printable file). As I don't have proper reference code with GPIO. I struck here to turn the projector on/off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raspberry Pi pin 1 (3V3) is not a GPIO.

GPIO 1 (which is what your code is switching) is on pin 28.

https://pinout.xyz/

Could you clarify what you are intending?

Individual GPIO can only provide a few milliamps, say 20 milliamps.

To control LED_ON_OFF connect a Pi GPIO to pin 3 of the device.  Also connect a ground wire between the Pi (say Pi pin 6) and the device (say device pin 14).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I thought the GPIO control connector has 14 pins and are same for the GPIO so I kept GPIO pin 1. IT doesn't matter which GPIO pin I should connect. I can connect it further.

Comment: I have changed the pin number from 1 to 5(It doesn't matter which GPIO pin I have to use) for no more confusion.

Comment: Could you edit your question and explain what you are trying to do?  You say switch LED on/off but then you mention serial link.

Comment: Done. I have edited and added 2 other pictures